# Using TextKit 2 to display tables in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, textkit

`UITextView` does not support any kind of tables, but I'm trying to create a text view implementation which would be able to show tables alongside normal text.

Basically: My macOS port uses `NSTextTable` to render some paragraphs next to each other when creating a PDF. I'm trying to come up with a way to achieve this on iOS.

Documentation and real-world implementations of TextKit 2 are still a bit hazy, but I'm interested if it would be possible to create my own content types using `NSTextElement` and `NSTextElementProvider`. If I'm reading it correctly, I'd define a range which is governed by my own implementation/layout?

As the documentation is so sparse, I'm very unsure how to actually implement an `NSTextElement` which would also be rendered as text when saved as a PDF — or if any of this would even be possible.

Any help or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, just looking to see if you have been able to implement this? I am trying to do the same, and am struggling with finding the right documentation/methods to do it. Thanks

Comment: @georgemp Yes, *sort of*. I managed to write a very elaborate view provider class which behaves in a similar way, but basically is just a view. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real way around the actual problem, but you can create a view provider which sort of acts like a table.

This example just supports one row, so it's basically just a column view, but you should be able to expand it pretty easily. Sizing the cells will be the trickiest part if you want to have a two-dimensional table.

The actual text attachment, which registers a view provider to display the fake table:

```
@objc public class TableAttachment:NSTextAttachment {
    // We need to forward these values to the provider when needed
    var cells:[TextTableCell]?
    var spacing = 0.0
    var margin = 0.0
    
    @objc public init(cells:[TextTableCell], spacing:CGFloat = 0.0, margin:CGFloat = 0.0) {
        NSTextAttachment.registerViewProviderClass(TextTableProvider.self, forFileType: "public.data")
        
        self.cells = cells
        self.spacing = spacing
        self.margin = margin
        
        super.init(data: nil, ofType: "public.data")
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
}
```

A label which acts as a table cell:

```swift
@objc public class TextTableCell:UILabel {
    var width = 0.0
    
    @objc public init(content:NSAttributedString, width: Double, height:Double = 0.0) {
        self.width = width

        let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: width, height: height)
        super.init(frame: rect)
                
        self.attributedText = content
        
        self.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        self.numberOfLines = 50 // Arbitrary value

        // Make the text field behave correctly in a PDF        
        self.layer.shouldRasterize = false
    }

    var height:CGFloat {
        guard var attributedText = self.attributedText  else { return 0.0 }        
        // Calculate frame size
        let rect = attributedText.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude), options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading], context: nil)
        
        self.frame.size.height = rect.size.height
        self.frame.origin.y = 0
        
        return self.frame.height
    }
}
```

And finally, the text attachment provider, which takes in a bunch of table cells and displays them.

```swift
@objc public class TextTableProvider : NSTextAttachmentViewProvider {
    var cells:[TextTableCell] = []
    var spacing = 0.0
    var margin = 0.0
    
    override init(textAttachment: NSTextAttachment, parentView: UIView?, textLayoutManager: NSTextLayoutManager?, location: NSTextLocation) {
        
        if let attachment = textAttachment as? TableAttachment {
            self.cells = attachment.cells ?? []
            self.spacing = attachment.spacing
            self.margin = attachment.margin
        }
        
        super.init(textAttachment: textAttachment, parentView: parentView, textLayoutManager: textLayoutManager, location: location)
        tracksTextAttachmentViewBounds = true
    }
    
    @objc public override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        
        view = UIView()

        // Add subviews
        var x = self.margin
        for column in self.cells {
            column.frame.origin.x = x
            view?.addSubview(column)
            
            x = spacing + CGRectGetMaxX(column.frame)
        }
    }

    /// Returns height of the tallest column in this view
    @objc public override func attachmentBounds(
        for attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any],
        location: NSTextLocation,
        textContainer: NSTextContainer?,
        proposedLineFragment: CGRect,
        position: CGPoint
    ) -> CGRect {
        var height = 0.0

        for column in self.cells {
            let colHeight = column.height 
            if colHeight > height { height = colHeight }
        }

        // I have no idea what this - 15.0 is, something for my own purposes, probably
        return CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: proposedLineFragment.width - 15.0, height: height)
    }
}
```